# Calling "clone()" on linux but it seems to malfunction

Tags: linux, gcc, process, gdb, clone

A simple test program, I expect it will "clone" to fork a child process, and each process can execute till its end

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sched.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<errno.h>
int f(void*arg)
{
pid_t pid=getpid();
printf("child pid=%d\n",pid);
}
char buf[1024];
int main()
{
    printf("before clone\n");
    int pid=clone(f,buf,CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK,NULL);
    if(pid==-1){
        printf("%d\n",errno);
        return 1;
    }
    waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
    printf("after clone\n");
    printf("father pid=%d\n",getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Ru it:

```
$g++ testClone.cpp && ./a.out
before clone
```

It didn't print what I expected. Seems after "clone" the program is in unknown state and then quit. I tried gdb and it prints:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at testClone.cpp:15
(gdb) n-
before clone
(gdb) n-
waiting for new child: No child processes.
(gdb) n-
Single stepping until exit from function clone@plt,-
which has no line number information.
```

If I remove the line of "waitpid", then gdb prints another kind of weird information.

```
(gdb) n-
before clone
(gdb) n-
Detaching after fork from child process 26709.
warning: Unexpected waitpid result 000000 when waiting for vfork-done
Cannot remove breakpoints because program is no longer writable.
It might be running in another process.
Further execution is probably impossible.
0x00007fb18a446bf1 in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
ptrace: No such process.
```

Where did I get wrong in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `clone` is a pointer to the child's stack.  As per the manual page for `clone(2)`:

> Stacks grow downward on all processors that run Linux (except the HP PA processors), so child_stack usually points to the topmost address  of  the memory space set up for the child stack.

Also, 1024 bytes is a paltry amount for a stack.  The following modified version of your program appears to run correctly:

```
// #define _GNU_SOURCE   // may be needed if compiled as C instead of C++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int f(void*arg)
{
    pid_t pid=getpid();
    printf("child pid=%d\n",pid);
    return 0;
}
char buf[1024*1024];   // *** allocate more stack ***
int main()
{
    printf("before clone\n");
    int pid=clone(f,buf+sizeof(buf),CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK,NULL);
         // *** in previous line: pointer is to *end* of stack ***
    if(pid==-1){
        printf("%d\n",errno);
        return 1;
    }
    waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
    printf("after clone\n");
    printf("father pid=%d\n",getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Also, @Employed Russian is right -- you probably shouldn't use `clone` except if you're trying to have some fun.  Either `fork` or `vfork` are more sensible interfaces to `clone` whenever they meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You should never call `clone` in a user-level program -- there are way too many restrictions on what you are allowed to do in the `clone`d process.

In particular, calling any `libc` function (such as `printf`) is a complete no-no (because `libc` doesn't know that your `clone` exists, and have not performed any setup for it).

As K. A. Buhr points out, you also pass too small a stack, and the wrong end of it. Your stack is also not properly aligned.

In short, even though K. A. Buhr's modification *appears* to work, it doesn't really.

TL;DR: `clone`, just *don't* use it.